# Joomla: image src path?

Tags: javascript, joomla

Doesn't work in Joomla this java script code? How change source path  in image tag?

```
function changetxt(name){ 
  var arr = new Array("btn1","btn2","btn3","btn4");
  var pic = new Array("ban_txt.png","ban_txt1.png","ban_txt.png","ban_txt1.png");
  var s="";

   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     if(arr[i]==name){
        document.getElementById(name).src="../../images/orange.png";
        document.getElementById(name).src="../../images/"+pic[i];       

     }
     else{
        document.getElementById(arr[i]).src="../images/grey.png";}
   }
```

Comment: Where is this function coming from? The source path is from `../../images/orange.png` so can't you simply change that?

Comment: How to write path for image in js folder. Not work path like  document.getElementById(name).src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/logo.png";

Answer (score 0):

Define site url and admin url and use it with your image src. It will surely work for you.

```js
function changetxt(name){
  
  var adminurl = "<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>";
  var siteurl = "<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>";
  
  var arr = new Array("btn1","btn2","btn3","btn4");
  var pic = new Array("ban_txt.png","ban_txt1.png","ban_txt.png","ban_txt1.png");
  var s="";

   for(var i=0;i`<`arr.length;i++){
     if(arr[i]==name){
        document.getElementById(name).src=adminurl+"images/orange.png";
        document.getElementById(name).src=adminurl+"images/"+pic[i];       

     }
     else{
        document.getElementById(arr[i]).src=siteurl+"images/grey.png";}
   }
```